# How should I calculate $\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+a^2/x^2)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+a^2/x^2)}\,dx$$

I even know the answer but indefinite integral is much more complicated than answer. The answer, according to Wolfram is $\sqrt{\pi/2}\,e^{-a}$.

Comment: How can a definite integral w.r.t. $x$ have an $x$ in the answer?

Comment: Oops, excuse me, in answer should be a instead of x.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+a^2/x^2)}\,dx. $$
Then under $x\to a^2x$, one has
$$I=\int_0^\infty a^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}a^2(x^2+1/x^2)}\,dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}a^2(x-1/x)^2}\,dx$$
Under $x-\frac1x \to x$, one can get the answer.