# How should I calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x-a\cdot(1/x)^b)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x-a\cdot(1/x)^b)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

A similiar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074208/how-should-i-calculate-int-0-infty-exp-x-a-xdx/4074225?noredirect=1#comment8418696_4074225) solved.
I even cannot get an answer from wolfram. Is there any thought on this problem?

Comment: The laplace transform might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $b$ is an integer and $a>0$, if we exclude the simple cases $b=0$ and $b=1$, we face Meijer G functions.

$$\color{blue}{I_b=\int_0^\infty \exp\Big[ x-\frac a {x^b}\Big]\,dx}$$

$$I_2=\frac {1} {\pi^{1/2}}G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{a}{2 ^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{2},1
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$I_3=\frac {\sqrt 3} {2\pi}G_{0,4}^{4,0}\left(\frac{a}{3^3}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},1
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$I_4=\frac {1} {\sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2}}G_{0,5}^{5,0}\left(\frac{a}{4^4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},1
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$I_5=\frac {\sqrt{5}} {4 \pi ^{2}}G_{0,6}^{6,0}\left(\frac{a}{5^5}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},1
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$I_6=\frac {\sqrt{3}} {4 \pi ^{5/2}}G_{0,7}^{7,0}\left(\frac{a}{6^6}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6},1
\end{array}
\right)$$
I suppose that we can conjecture that
$$\color{red}{I_b=\sqrt{b \,(2 \pi )^{1-b}}\,\,G_{0,(b+1)}^{(b+1),0}\left(\frac{a}{b^b}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{b},\frac{2}{b},\cdots,\frac{b-1}{b},1
\end{array}
\right)}$$