# Derive compound Gaussian distribution consisting of a complex normal distribution with normal distributed variance

Tags: probability, integration, complex-analysis, statistics

We  want to derive a distribution from two Gaussian distributions using the definition of a compound distribution
$$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \quad f(z) = \int g(z|\theta) h(\theta) \,\text{d}\theta \qquad \qquad \qquad (*)
$$
More specific, we would like to use $(*)$ when $g(z|\sigma)$ is the pdf of a 1D complex normal distribution (ie $Z \sim \mathcal{CN}(0, |\sigma|^2)$), where $\Sigma \sim N(0, \tilde{\sigma}^2)$ with pdf $h(\sigma)$. The complex normal distribution will be defined
$$
g(z|\sigma) = \frac{1}{\pi \sigma^2}e^\frac{|z|^2}{\sigma^2}, \qquad z\in\mathbb{C}, 
$$
where $\sigma$ is normally distributed
$$
h(\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\tilde{\sigma}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2} \sigma^2\right), \qquad \sigma\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

From the definition in $(*)$ we then get an integral
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi \sigma^2}e^\frac{|z|^2}{\sigma^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\tilde{\sigma}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2} \sigma^2\right) \, \text{d} \sigma = 2 \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi \sigma^2}e^\frac{|z|^2}{\sigma^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\tilde{\sigma}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2} \sigma^2\right) \, \text{d} \sigma,
\end{align}
$$
where the last step comes from that the function is even.

Hence, we end up with an integral similar to the one below.
$$
\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{1}{\sigma^2} - \sigma^2\right)\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\, \text{d} \sigma.
$$
And if we make the substitution $x = 1/\sigma$ => $\text{d}x = -1/\sigma^2 \text{d} \sigma$, we get
$$
-\int_{-\infty}^0 \exp\left(-x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\, \text{d} x
$$
According to integral calculator this should have a solution (but not an analytical solution) consisting of erfc factors. I suppose you can rewrite this as a normal distribution but I cant understand how exactly.

Comment: According to Maple the resulting distribution will be a Weibull distribution.

Comment: Maybe I’m misreading, but it seems you’re saying the covariance is normally distributed?

Comment: Probably bad notation from my part to use $\Sigma$. What I mean is that the 1D complex normal distribution a has variance which is normally distributed.

Comment: So the variance can take negative values in your model, right? Hm.

Comment: Aah now I see what you meant by variance can take negative values. Once again, my bad. My previous comment meant to say the 1D complex normal distribution a has standard deviation which is normally distributed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find how to link stack exchange posts to each other, but thanks to Did and Tony in

[How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2-1/x^2)dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106965/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-exp-x2-1-x2dx?fbclid=IwAR2qAAF1iZDXlXbjo-ULgVOHD64LRYWhnHd6WQbOntJEeWWdAESPoOGyFiU)

and Matthew Zhukov and xpaul in

[How should I calculate $\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+a^2/x^2)}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466028/how-should-i-calculate-int-0-infty-e-frac12x2a2-x2-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

for helping us find the answer. If you have time please upvote them.

The answer itself is the complex Weibull distribution
$$
\begin{align*}
    f(z) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \pi \tilde{\sigma}} \frac{1}{|z|} \exp\left(- \frac{\sqrt{2} |z|}{\tilde{\sigma}}\right),
\end{align*}
$$